# Need ListView based on user input, with additional functionality

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to work on a Logistics app for Android. My app shall take a list of addresses from the user and display them in a ListView. The user should be able to edit or remove a component address from the listview as required. I am considering an expandable listview for this purpose with the addresses serving as parent components with remove/edit functions making up the child component of each address. Should I be looking at any other features within android studio for this requirement?

Additional info-
My project is in Java.

Comment: Recyclerview will get you much farther. Additionally there is some powerful 3rd party RecyclerView libraries that will make this system much easier

Comment: use reclyclerview

Comment: Thanks looks like this will work.